# Laravel Blade Component onclick function

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is it possible on blade component to call a function from onclick, and change its variable value?

```js
 public $rental = true;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.product-rental');
    }
    public function toggleRental(){
        $this->rental = !$this->rental;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-6">
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="rental" type="checkbox" @click="toggleRental()" id="rental" value="1" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="rental">Rental</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{$rental}}
```

Basically, what i want is when i CLICK a button, it will call the "toggleRental()" function from blade component and update the "$rental" variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using [Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/) instead.

It provides exactly this kind of features.

Otherwise you should implement an API endpoint and use Javascript to do so.

EDIT:

So you can use something like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-6">
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="rental" type="checkbox" data-rental="{{ $rental }}" onclick="toggleRental" id="rental" value="1" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="rental">Rental</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{$rental}}
```

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var rentalCheckBox = document.querySelector('#rental');
    rentalCheckBox.value = rentalCheckBox.getAttribute('data-rental');
    function toggleRental(){
        rentalCheckBox.value = !rentalCheckBox.value;
    } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but i believe livewire calls from backend which I dont prefer for this functionality. Because i think its best to handle this part on front end and not involve any backend calls.

Comment: So use some kind of Javscript if you don't need data changes in back-end.
I will edit the answer and add some suggestions.

Comment: I misunderstood the purpose of blade component, you are right. Javascript is the best way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: [You should definitely use Livewire. It's really great and does all things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)